# Returning all results of an outer query and getting a count of attached items

Tags: mysql, sql

So I'm struggling to write a query that returns me all categories regardless of what filter I have applied but the count changes based on how many returned recipes there will be in this filter.

This query works nice if I don't apply any filters to it. The count's seem right, but as soon as I add something like this: `where c.parent_id is not null and r.time_cook_minutes > 60` I am filtering out most of the categories instead of just getting a count of zero.

here's an example query that I came up with that does not work the way I want it to:

```
select t.id, t.name, t.parent_id, a.cntr from categories as t,
   (select c.id, count(*) as cntr from categories as c 
   inner join recipe_categories as rc on rc.category_id = c.id
   inner join recipes as r on r.id = rc.recipe_id 
   where c.parent_id is not null and r.time_cook_minutes > 60
   group by c.id) as a
where a.id = t.id
group by t.id
```

so this currently, as you might imagine, returns only the counts of recipes that exist in this filter subset... what I'd like is to get all of them regardless of the filter with a count of 0 if they don't have any recipes under that filter.

any help with this would be greatly appreciated. If this question is not super clear let me know, and I can elaborate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for nested join if you move the condition into a regular outer join:

```
select t.id, t.name, t.parent_id, count(r.id)
from categories as t
left join recipe_categories as rc on rc.category_id = c.id
left join recipes as r on r.id = rc.recipe_id
   and r.time_cook_minutes > 60
where c.parent_id is not null
group by 1, 2, 3
```

Notes:

- Use `left` joins so you always get every category
- Put `r.time_cook_minutes > 60` on the *left join* condition. Leaving it on the `where` clause cancels the effect of `left`

Comment: you rock! Thank you for this! I'm curious what `group by 1, 2, 3` does. I've never seen that before. Thanks again for your answer. :)

Comment: @alex `group by 1, 2, 3` is a shorter way of coding `group by <column1>, <column2>, <column3>` and is supported by just about every database. It’s particulary handy when a column is an expression, but I always use it because I favor less code.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use conditional aggregation, moving the `WHERE` clause into a `CASE` (or `IF()` for MySQL) statement wrapped in a `SUM()` of 1's and 0's (i.e., counts). Also, be sure to consistently use the explicit join, the current industry practice in SQL. While your derived table uses this form of join, the outer query uses implicit join matching IDs in `WHERE` clause.

```
select t.id, t.name, t.parent_id, a.cntr 
from categories as t
inner join
   (select c.id, sum(case when c.parent_id is not null and r.time_cook_minutes > 60
                          then 1 
                          else 0
                     end) as cntr 
    from categories as c 
    inner join recipe_categories as rc on rc.category_id = c.id
    inner join recipes as r on r.id = rc.recipe_id 
    group by c.id) as a
on a.id = t.id
group by t.id
```

Comment: This works great! Thank you for your answer! Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want:

```
select c.id, c.name, c.parent_id, count(r.id)
from categories c left join
     recipe_categories rc
     on rc.category_id = c.id left join
     recipes r
     on r.id = rc.recipe_id and r.time_cook_minutes > 60
where c.parent_id is not null and 
group by c.id, c.name, c.parent_id;
```

Notes:

- This uses `left join`s for all the joins.
- It aggregates by all the non-aggregated columns.
- It counts matching recipes rather than all rows.
- The condition on recipes is moved to the `on` clause from the `where` clause.

Comment: Awesome!!! thank you for your answer! Much appreciated. I was struggling with this for quite some time.